# UIPicker selection appears white

Tags: swift, uipickerview

I am having some trouble implementing the UIPicker.
When I view it, some rows appear white/transparent. After scrolling a bit and coming back the row finally appear.

Here is the screenshot:

1st row staying white

[image]

2nd row as well while scrolling on it

[image]

Rows finally appear after fully scrolling and returning on them

[image]

Here is the code

```
// reinitializing array to nil
pickerContentArray = []

for i in 0..<specialitiesList.count {
    pickerContentArray.append(specialitiesList[i]["name"] as! String)
}

picker.reloadAllComponents()
picker.selectRow(0, inComponent: 0, animated: false)
```

---

```
    //MARK: - Delegates and data sources
//MARK: Data Sources
func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return pickerContentArray.count
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusingView view: UIView!) -> UIView
{
    var pickerLabel = UILabel()
    pickerLabel.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()

    if pushedButton == "Speciality" {
        pickerLabel.text = specialitiesList[row]["name"] as? String
        pickerLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 12)
    } else if pushedButton == "Status" {
        pickerLabel.text = statusList[row]
        pickerLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 16)
    } else if pushedButton == "City" {
        pickerLabel.text = citiesList[row]["name"] as? String
        pickerLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 16)
    }

    pickerLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    return pickerLabel
}

//MARK: Delegates
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
    return pickerContentArray[row]
}
```

Thank you,

Comment: Can you share your data source and delegate code for the picker?

Comment: @hennes, I added the methods in my question.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you are calling your setup code too early.

Try to do it in `viewWillAppear()` instead of `viewDidLoad()`.

Also, it could be that because you select the component without animation, the component does not update properly. You should pass `false` for animation before the view is shown, but `true` if the picker is already visible to the user.

Comment: I'm actually updating the picker when user push a button so the setup is done after.

Comment: Then it might have to do with your lacking animation. See addition to my answer.

Comment: Thanks. Tried to put 'animated: true' but it is still not working.

Comment: I removed the following line picker.selectRow(0, inComponent: 0, animated: false) .
And it works fine now.
Any idea on why this is not working?

Comment: Fixed it by putting picker.selectRow(0, inComponent: 0, animated: false) after the animation I had right after my piece of code. Did the job well :)